# How to call multiple separate sql query in one stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, stored-procedures, mysqli

I have stored procedure that I created in MySQL and want PHP to call that stored procedure.

Here is my stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `getNodeName` $$
CREATE FUNCTION `getTreeNodeName`(`nid` int) RETURNS varchar(25) CHARSET utf8
BEGIN
 DECLARE nodeName varchar(25);

 SELECT name into nodeName FROM tree
 WHERE id = nid;

 SELECT user FROM user_master
 WHERE status = 'Y';

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

i'm getting first query result but i can't able to get second query result anyone help me...

Comment: does this help: https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/73714/#562711